# Creating a box shadow like a deep color of the element's background

Tags: jquery, html, css

So css3 new feature is box-shadow . Is there any way to create a box shadow of an element like the element's background color?

### For e.g:

`<button class="btn-blue">`

and it has css:
   `.btn-blue{background: blue}`

### so i want to drop shadow like a color light deep blue with css :

`.btn-blue{box-shadow : 2px 2px 2px #489EFD}`

Is there any way to create that shadow without another way ? Coz if i have 10 different colors i have to define 10 extra css hex/rgba/hsla color for box shadow . i want to reduce them.

### Note

I have tried `inset` with `rgba(0,0,0,.3)` : It works fine with solid bg . But when there is an white bg with solid border it looks black

Comment: I would do that in JS. Get the current bg color of the element you want to apply a shadow to, calculate the new color and apply the correct shadow color

Answer (score 0):

you could use a small piece of jquery to loop through each button element, and apply the box shadow. For example,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('button').each(function() { /*loop through each button element*/
    var col = $(this).css("background-color"); /*get its background color*/
    $(this).css("box-shadow", "2px 2px 5px " + col); /*apply a box shadow*/
  });
});
```

```css
.btn-blue {background: blue}
.btn-red {background: red}
.btn-green {background: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-blue">button1</button>
<button class="btn-red">button2</button>
<button class="btn-green">button3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use the command inset like this :

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #000 inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #000 inset;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #000 inset;
```